# Библиотеки requests and BeautifulSoup не работает код из учебника

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Изучаю Python, в книге (Автоматизация рутинных задачь с помощью Python) есть код который должен открывать первые 5 ссылок по запросу на гугл, но что-то не так,  в классе тега указан "r", открываю в гугле там совсем другой, я подставляю соответсвующий, он всё равно не работает, если пытаюсь найти все теги , выводит список из примерно 80-90 ссылок, и первые 5 точно не те которые нужно выбрать, помогите разобраться, возможно уже что-то устарело, т.к. книга 2016 года. Перепробовал уже много чего, сижу над ним вторую неделю.

```
#! python3
# lucky.py - Opens several Google search results.

import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4

print('Googling...') # display text while downloading the Google page
res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()

# Retrieve top search result links.
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

# Open a browser tab for each result.
linkElems = soup.select('.r a')
numOpen = min(5, len(linkElems))
for i in range(numOpen):
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

Comment: `res.raise_for_status()` у вас с етой строчкой проблемы. + c 2016 года в bs4 могло много чего измениться, рекомендую перейти на учебник по новее

Comment: Благодарю за рекомендацию, но эта строка проверяет правильность ответа на запрос, в случае если requests.get() не получит ответ от сервера, программа выдаст ошибку,   к этой строке как раз вопросов нет.

Comment: Используйте selenium для парсинга вместо requests